# Save PDF file that is created from code

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, model-view-controller

I have a PNG file that is used as a Template, then I use PDFSharp.Drawing to write over the image which in turn produces a Certificate as a PDF, as shown below:

```
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
document.Info.Title = "Created with PDFsharp";

// Create an empty page 
PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
page.Width = 419;
page.Height = 595;
page.Orientation = PdfSharp.PageOrientation.Landscape;

// Get an XGraphics object for drawing 
XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

// Draw background
gfx.DrawImage(XImage.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/Certificate/MyCertificate.png")), 0, 0, 595, 419);

// Create fonts
XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.Regular);

// Draw the text and align on page.
gfx.DrawString("Name", font, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(0, 77, page.Width, 157), XStringFormats.Center);
```

This can open this in my default PDF Viewer (Edge in my case) and I am able to save from there, but when I try to save from the Site and not the PDF viewer I only save the Template and not any of the Text which is written over.

My code to Save the file is here:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MyCertificate.pdf");

Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/Certificate/MyCertificate.png"));

Response.End();
```

I'm fairly certain that the reason I am only saving the Template is because I set the Server MapPath to the location of the template, but the finished certificate is never actually saved on our side.

How can I save the PDF (with the text) instead of just the template if it is not saved anywhere before-hand on my side?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you send `png` to client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write the PDF to the browser using a `MemoryStream`. Adding the PDF name to the header with `AppendHeader` does not send it to the browser.

```
//create an empty byte array
byte[] bin;

//'using' ensures the MemoryStream will be disposed correctly
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    //save the pdf to the stream
    document.Save(stream, false);

    //fill the byte array with the pdf bytes from stream
    bin = stream.ToArray();
}

//clear the buffer stream
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;

//set the correct ContentType
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

//set the correct length of the string being send
Response.AddHeader("content-length", bin.Length.ToString());

//set the filename for the pdf
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"MyCertificate.pdf\"");

//send the byte array to the browser
Response.OutputStream.Write(bin, 0, bin.Length);

//cleanup
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```